# Three.js - adding a simple right-click context menu

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm really struggling to add a right-click context menu to my scene in Three.js. The issue is that I also have some HTML sliders in the header of my page, and the moment I add the following lines, the sliders stop working:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
```

Also, for the examples I've seen, there was a focus on right-clicking on a specific object in the scene. I just want a simple solution where I can right-click anywhere in the scene, and the menu pops up.

Can someone give me such an example please?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want the right click menu on the three.js canvas, just add the event listener to the three.js canvas instead of the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning event listeners to the entire document with `document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);` may give you undesired results when trying to use a slider. Maybe you should assign the listeners to the canvas alone, which is much more detailed and doesn't encompass the whole HTML doc:

`renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);`

You can see [in the docs, `.domElement`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.domElement) is the `<canvas>` so your sliders shouldn't be affected by these listeners.